# Probability distribution CDF, checking my answer

Tags: probability

Suppose that a large grocery store has shelf space for 150 cartons of fruit drink that are delivered on a
particular day of each week. The weekly sale for fruit drink shows that the demand increases steadily up to 100 cartons and then levels off between 100 and 150 cartons. Let Y denote the weekly demand in hundreds
of cartons. It is known that the pdf of Y can be approximated by:

$$f (y) = \begin{cases}
y,       0 ≤ y ≤ 1 \\1,         1 < y ≤ 1.5 \\ 0, \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

Find $F(y)$:

I got my answer as:

$y^2/2 \ \  \text{for } \ 0 < y < 1$

$y \ \ \text{for} \ 1 < y < 1.5$

$1,  \text{elsewhere}$

Whereas the book's answer is $y - 0.5$ for the second argument. I don't understand how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the third interval ($I_3$) of the cdf you have to regard the value of the whole second interval ($I_2$):

$$I_3=\int_0^1 t \ dt+\int_1^y 1 \ dt$$

The reason is that the (continuous) cdf integrates all values from $-\infty$ to $y$, not only from $1$ to $y$: $P(Y\leq y)$

---

By the way, the first interval is $0, y< 0$ and the last interval is $1, y\geq 1.5$

$$F(y)=\begin{cases} 0, y\ < 0 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (I_1)  \\ \frac{y^2}{2}, 0 \leq  y < 1 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (I_2) \\ \int_0^1 t \ dt+\int_1^y 1 \ dt, \ 1\leq y<1.5 \quad \qquad (I_3)  \\ 1, y\geq 1.5 \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (I_4) \end{cases}$$

Comment: The value of the first interval is half. But why is there a minus sign?

Comment: @user585380 Yes, you are right the first interval is $0.5$ Now you add $\int_1^y 1 \ dt$. I think you can manage that und you will see how the $-0.5$ is obtained.

Comment: Let me know if this is right - if you integrate 1, that is y and with the bounds - the answer become y - 1. So the total is 0.5 + y - 1, which gives us y - 0.5.

Comment: Yes, you got it! Let me repeat: At the **cdf** you have no elsewhere. You have to distinguish between  $F(y)=0$ and $F(y)=1$

Comment: Thank you for the help! Got it. I won't use the word "elsewhere" in a CDF again.

Comment: You´re welcome. That´s a good idea.